# How can i detect video if streaming is stopped from webrtc initiator?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm using webrtc for screensharing application. Everything works without problem. But when user right click to something and click "run as administrator" video streaming is stopped. ( because desktop screen changes to secure desktop. At that moment i get following error logs on console ( Visual studio Code )

DxgiDuplicatorController failed to capture desktop, error code Initialization failed
Capture: Unable to get cursor info. Error = 5

same logs repeat until screen changes back to normal desktop again.

My Question is how can i detect that it cannot capture screen for streaming  ? 
How can i know video streaming is stopped ? or blank or empty stream ?

Comment: Check for track [ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/ended_event)?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried  const [track] = stream.getVideoTracks();
track.addEventListener('ended', () => console.log('track ended')); and stream.oninactive = function () {
                        console.log('track ended');
                      };
But when uac dialog is on stream stops but those events not getting called.

Comment: Is this in a browser? Which one? Does capture resume once you switch back to normal desktop, or is it fatal? If fatal, I'd file a bug on the browser (or lib) to fire the `ended` event. If not fatal, I'd examine all track properties for clues.

Comment: Hello again. i capture screen with electron application and send it to chrome browser. yes after screen is back to normal it continues to stream normal desktop. i think somehow i need to understand video tracks contains black or empty screen. if i can understand it i can say that secure desktop is displayed. i tried to catch if video is in muted state but this also not working.

Comment: I found it :)  i was setting event handler for onmute event but it was after peer is created. When i replace and set event handler before webrtc peer is created i can catch video mute as i wish.  


const [track] = stream.getVideoTracks();
track.onmute = () => console.log('Video muted');
StartPeer(stream);

Thank you so much for your help. I accept your comment as answer because it redirected me to correct way.